# Facebook login works fine in browser but doesn't work on android with phonegap

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova

After about 2 days of trying to implement every version of the phonegap facebook plugin i decided to give up on it and to implement plain JS login system in my app. To be honest, native login system is just not worth handling this plugin...

I followed the instructions on the facebook developer site and my login works perfectly on desktop browsers. The problem begins after i compile it with phonegap and try to run it on an android device. 
When i Press the login button I'm getting a
"FB is not defined at..."
this results from the attempt to access the FB.login() method.

Relevant code is :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX', // contains my App ID
        channelUrl : 'YYYYYYYYYYYY', // contains my Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });


    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs.
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            testAPI();
            active_access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            $.mobile.changePage("#main_page");
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            FB.login();
        } else {
            FB.login();
        }
    });

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
    console.log ("async load started!");
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));


function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
}
```

Button wiring:

```
function set_buttons() {
    $("#facebook_login_button").click(function(){
        console.log("login attempt");
        FB.login();
    });
```

Again, This works perfectly in browser. I just cant make it work on android after phonegap compile.

Ideas?

Comment: have you whitelisted the facebook website?

Comment: added connect.facebook.net etc. to the config.xml.    <access origin="connect.facebook.net" />

Comment: It's white listed (I verified it by logging in from the desktop version).and access origin is defined as:  <access origin="*" /> so it shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , i figured it out...

since I'm running it from a locahost I added "http:" to

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
```

So now it's:

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
```

Comment: In my case it is not working any other solution @z_av please provide!

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to your Facebook´s app > Setting > Advanced and add the correct urls on 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs'

Answer (score 0):

For me it had to do with adding BundleID on developers facebook app settings under iOS section. 
This may help some other person in my boat.